# Forward accessibility scroll not working

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, uiaccessibility

This problem has been bothering me for few days now, I have probably tried looking all the questions available but nothing seems to solve my problem.

I have a UIPageViewController and when VO is on backward 3 finger scroll is working but when I try forward 3 finger swipe it just says page 1 of 2 but doesn't scroll or swipes.

UIPageViewController has UIViewControllers in it, which shows HTML content, if I set my

```
UIViewController.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

Then it scrolls to next but obviously doesn't get into reading content of view controller.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried overriding, what I'm noticing is thats being called only for backward scrolls when I try forward scrolling (swipe for next view controller) this is not even called.

```
 accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool
```

Any help will be useful.